# Is there a way to share RxSwift's observable operator like just, from, of, etc?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I'm trying to share the result from mapping observables produced by `just()` operator.

```
let observable = Observable.just(())
  .map { _ -> String in
    print("block is called")
    return "some transformation"
  }
  .share()

observable
  .subscribe()
  .disposed(by: disposeBag)

observable
  .subscribe()
  .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

But the code produces result twice:

```
block is called
block is called
```

I want the `map()` to be called once only so I thought `share()` would be enough. Is there a way to share the result produced by the sample code?

Comment: FYI, you should not have side effects inside a `map` operator so the fact that it is called twice should not be an issue.

Comment: The code is just for demonstration only and the `map()` getting called twice when shared is an issue because it should not have called multiple times in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**
Just use `.forever` scope like this: `.share(scope: .forever)`

**Long answer:**
Default value for scope is `.whileConnected`. This means that this observable will share values while somebody is subscribed. Let's see if it is so in your case
You can add extra logging like this

```swift
let observable = Observable.just(())
    .map { _ -> String in
        print("block is called")
        return "some transformation"
      }
    .share()
    .debug("Debug") // Change is here

    observable
      .subscribe()
      .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    observable
      .subscribe()
      .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Log result is

```
2020-04-20 08:18:46.947: Debug -> subscribed
block is called
2020-04-20 08:18:46.954: Debug -> Event next(some transformation)
2020-04-20 08:18:46.954: Debug -> Event completed
2020-04-20 08:18:46.955: Debug -> isDisposed
2020-04-20 08:18:46.955: Debug -> subscribed
block is called
2020-04-20 08:18:46.956: Debug -> Event next(some transformation)
2020-04-20 08:18:46.956: Debug -> Event completed
2020-04-20 08:18:46.956: Debug -> isDisposed
```

So you can see that your first subscription ends immediately after the `.subscribe()` call, that's why the observable is not sharing the value

It happens because by default subscription and observation happens on immediate scheduler, right in the thread the observable was created on. So actually this code is synchronous!

In this case you can either change share scope to `.forever` or just observe asynchronously on some other thread, in this case `MainScheduler.asyncInstance` will do the job.

Also I want to notice that `share` function has another parameter which is replay count which is `0` by default. This means that it will share all the events the observable has produced. With long sequences it can cause high memory usage and it is some you should look out for. To prevent OOM, you can set count to 1

```swift
share(replay: 1, scope: .forever)
```

Comment: I don't think `share()` means replay all the events the observable has produced. `share()` means observe only the events emitted after the subscription. I learned it here btw: https://medium.com/gett-engineering/rxswift-share-ing-is-caring-341557714a2d

Comment: It actually means. You can reproduce it by replacing `Observable.just(())` with  `Observable.from([(), (), (), ()])`. You will see "block is called" four times

Comment: It is because you use `from()` which emits events one by one. I think your example has nothing to do with `share()`. Also, I tried your example and it produced two the same results for `share(replay: 0` and `share(replay: 1)`, which is the "block is called" is printed four times.